# part of the path not found

Tags: c#, logging, encryption, filestream

```
    private void btnDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = "";
        int i = 0;
        string listpath = @"c\yearsLog\2015.txt";
        string writePath = @"c\logs.txt";
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(listpath);
        long counter = CountLinesInFile(listpath);
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            temp = file.ReadLine().Replace("....", "");
            CreateNewLogFiles(Decryption(temp),writePath);
        }
        file.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Log Dosyanız tamamlandı.");


    }
```

I want to only write the file of Decrypt(2015.txt) to logs.txt but it respose me a part of path dont find.Can someone help me? what can I do

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `Drive` letters with  `:` colon

Try This:

```
string listpath = @"c:\yearsLog\2015.txt";
string writePath = @"c:\logs.txt";
```

**Solution 2:**

```
private void btnDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = "";
        int i = 0;
        string listpath = @"c:\yearsLog\2015.txt";
        if(File.Exists(listpath))
        {
        string writePath = @"c:\logs.txt";
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(listpath);
        long counter = CountLinesInFile(listpath);
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            temp = file.ReadLine().Replace("....", "");
            CreateNewLogFiles(Decryption(temp),writePath);
        }
        file.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Log Dosyanız tamamlandı.");
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("File "+listpath+" not found");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I already use----- string listpath = @"c:\yearsLog\2015.txt";
string writePath = @"c:\logs.txt";

Comment: @akdrmrk: okay but in your question there is no `colon` for drive letters

Comment: @akdrmrk: it is sure that there is no directory `yearsLog` in your `C:`drive check it first

Comment: I am sure. I have 2015.txt in yearsLog folder in C:

Comment: @akdrmrk: you can check wether file exists o not by using File.Exists(), try my edited answer with `solution2` , please let me know the result

Comment: if(File.Exists(listpath))
            {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(listpath);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("does not exist");

Comment: @BenVoigt: sorry i forgot to change the drive letters with colon , edited answer

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi File does not exist :S

Comment: @akdrmrk: did you try with `C:\yearsLog` because i forgot to change the drive letters with colon.

Comment: file does not exist. I have two file read and write, I don t understand what is problem

Comment: I did solution2 ----File not found